# Duda específica con el objeto this en Javascript

Tags: javascript, this

Quisiera expresar mi duda, a partir de estos dos ejemplos.

```
const obj = {
  nombre: 'Ulises',
  saludar: function(){
    console.log(`Hola, yo soy ${this.nombre}.`);
  }
};

obj.saludar();
```

En este ejemplo invoco el método del objeto en el cual me retorna el saludo. Pero en el siguiente caso, al guardarlo en una variable, en lugar de saludar me retorna undefined.

```
const obj = {
  nombre: 'Ulises',
  saludar: function(){
    console.log(`Hola, yo soy ${this.nombre}.`);
  }
};

const saludo = obj.saludar;
saludo();
```

Me gustaría saber a que se debe dicho retorno.

Answer (score 3):

Buen día,

En tu segundo ejemplo lo que haces es asignar la función `saludar()` a la variable `saludo`. Únicamente `saludar()`, por lo que `saludo` no contiene al elemento `nombre` y por eso sale `undefined` porque adentro de `saludo`, `nombre` no está definido.

En otras palabras, lo que haces es que `saludo` sea una instancia de `obj.saludar` por lo que `nombre` no se define adentro de `saludo`.

Si desearas que `saludo` fuera una instancia de `obj` entonces tendría que ser así:

```js
const obj = {
  nombre: 'Ulises',
  saludar: function(){
    console.log(`Hola, yo soy ${this.nombre}.`);
  }
};

const saludo = obj;
saludo.saludar();
```

### Edición

Otra cosa que podrías hacer es utilizar `apply` para pasarle el parámetro del nombre a `saludo`:

```js
const obj = {
  nombre: 'Ulises',
  saludar: function(){
    console.log('Hola, yo soy ' + this.nombre);
  }
};

const saludo = obj.saludar;
saludo.apply({nombre: 'Heytale Pazguato'});
```

De esa forma ya no queda indefinido.

Answer (score 2):

Si bien la respuesta del compañero @HeytalePazguato es correcta, quiero añadir un poco de teoría: `this` siempre hace referencia al contexto del padre. Al usarse dentro de una función declarada dentro de un objeto, `this` hace referencia al objeto padre, ergo tienes disponible la variable `nombre`. Al asignar la función a una variable en el "flujo principal", `this` pasa a hacer referencia al padre de dicha variable... que en este caso será el objeto `window` si se ejecuta en un navegador.

Esto podemos probarlo fácilmente con el siguiente snippet :)

```js
const obj = {
  nombre: 'Ulises',
  saludar: function(){
    console.log(`Hola, yo soy ${this.nombre}.`);
  }
};
// Definimos la variable nombre en el objeto window, a ver si ya no es undefined!
window['nombre'] = 'perico';

const saludo = obj.saludar;
saludo();
```